# UserName and Password information can be seen on https

Tags: zap

During scanning my https website via owasp zap , I found that username and password information is not encrypted. What could be the reason and how to fix. Please see below screenshot of ZAP.[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with zap, so maybe I'm missing something. What seems to be the problem? As far as I can tell, the username and password are sent on an `https://` connection, so they _are_ encrypted.

Comment: Concern is that they are not encrypted. Is this SSL certificate issue?

Comment: @MuhammadAliKhamis ZAP is a man-in-the-middle proxy, meaning that it sits in the middle of a normally-encrypted connection. The *only* reason it can do this is that you trusted its certificate on the client, which allows it to impersonate the server.

Comment: @Gilles: The communication channel is encrypted, the credentials are transmitted over the encrypted communication channel in plain text.

Comment: @GordonDavisson how about chrome dev tools (inspect element). I can see there also.

Comment: Chrome knows the cleartext, because it is on one end of the End-to-End encryption. 

And as @Jeroen-ITNerdbox hast stated, they get transmitted in clear text _inside_ the encrypted channel.

Answer (score 5):

OWASP ZAP is like a MITM proxy very similar to Burp suite.Ofcourse it can read the https because you must have installed a Root CA certificate while setting it up.There is nothing wrong with your website in regards to your question

Comment: I can see the information via chrome inspect. Is this still due to Root CA certificate?

Comment: @MuhammadAliKhamis If you mean the browser dev tools, well, obviously you can; the browser does all the encryption (and decryption) so it knows both the plaintext and the ciphertext, and the dev tools would be quite useless if they showed ciphertext instead of plaintext.